# How to paste a backslash character to a string?

Tags: regex, r, string, character-encoding, paste

How can I paste a backslash character?

```
ToPrintOnFile = paste("hello", "\", "World")
Error: unexpected symbol in "paste("hello", "\", "World"
```

If I try to escape this character with an extra "\"..

```
ToPrintOnFile = paste("hello", "\\", "World")
[1] "hello \\ World"
```

My goal is to write `ToPrintOnFile` on a file, where `ToPrintOnFile` contains a single backslash character (and not two that follows).

Thks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to use double escapes to represent a single backslash character. Your second attempt works as expected. Use `cat()` to print the string and see for yourself or `nchar("\\")`

```
cat(paste("hello", "\\", "World"))
# hello \ World
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it would appears with only one backslash once it is `cat`. Thank you!

Comment: @Remi.b There are NOT two backslashes in "\\" when entered on the R command line. If you doubt me, then just type `nchar("\\")`

Comment: That is quite interesting actually. It also solved my problem but I am wondering now if I got the reason behind all this. Because if I View() an object with "\\" in a string, RStudio also shows two backslashes. If i write this e.g. into a .csv, then only one backslash survives. So R simply is Showing the escape character as well in its GUI, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cat("Hello","\\","World")
```